Не получилось связать Firebase и Google Analytics + были потеряны данные Firebase
Товарищи, всем привет!
Пытался связать Firebase с GA и что-то пошло не так… помогите, пожалуйста, починить
Есть аккаунт 1 Google Analytics в котором есть данные по веб-сайту. Хочется его связать с проектом 1 Firebase в котором есть (были) данные по Android приложению.
В этом аккаунте 1 GA не было потоков данных для iOS или для Android, был только для web.  При этом была установлена связь с каким-то проектом 2 firebase https://joxi.ru/bmo1vW0solYzRA , к которому нет доступа.
А в проекте 1 Firebase была установлена связь с аккаунтом 2 GA, в котором не было данных с сайта, были только из приложения.
Почитав справку и спросив ChatGPT сделал следующее (делал другой человек, с демо экрана, я могу упускать какие-то детали):
-В проекте 1 Firebase зашел в раздел интеграций и удалил текущую связь с аккаунтом 2 GA http://joxi.ru/8AnkB6pc0KJlpr
-Собирался установить связь с нужным аккаунтом 1 GA, он был доступен для выбора в выпадающей плашке, но связь не устанавливалась  появилась красная плашка что у нас недостаточно прав. Хотя в аккаунте 1 GA  права администратора, а в проекте 1 Firebase права оунера.
-Установили обратно связь проекта 1 Firebase  с аккаунтом 2 GA  (при этом создался автоматически создался новый ресурс) - http://joxi.ru/krDBxOjiLdYpY2
Что есть сейчас:
-Пропали ивенты в проекте 1 Firebase http://joxi.ru/n2Y9OkZuV0zg42  и все накопленные данные по юзерам http://joxi.ru/Grq7yLvuyb9XB2
-Нет никакой связи между нужными GA и Firebase.
Вопросы:
1 Есть ли какой-то способ восстановить пропавшие данные в Firebase? ChatGPT кстати говорит что это «возможно, это временная проблема, связанная с синхронизацией данных после удаления интеграции. Дайте системе немного времени для восстановления данных.». Но мне ему уже не верится.
2 Что не так было в наших действиях? Ну кроме поверить ChatGPT)
3 Как все-таки настроить нужную интеграцию?
